# how can i use only one file instead of 4 php files that are basically the same?

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

i basically have a simple porgram to count how many times a click a specific button and then send it to mysql, but for each button i have diferent tables and separated files. I would like to know if there is any way to join the 4 files into only one, since it is repeating the same thing 4 times in diferent files.
Here is my code:

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Fct</title>
</head>
<body>
<form  action="inserir.php" method="post">
   <button name="A" type="submit" value="A">Senha A</button>
</form>

<form  action="inserir2.php" method="post">
   <button name="B" type="submit" value="B">Senha B</button>
</form>

<form  action="inserir3.php" method="post">
   <button name="C" type="submit" value="C">Senha C</button>
</form>

<form  action="inserir4.php" method="post">
   <button name="D" type="submit" value="D">Senha D</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

and then the file to insert into mysql witch is inserir.php;

```
<?php
include 'bdados.php';

$A = $_POST['A'];

$query = "INSERT into `tipo1`(`senhaa`) VALUES (  '$A' )";


mysqli_query($dbconn, $query);

header("location: index.php");



 ?>
```

basically i have 4 "inserir.php" and i think i could shrink those 4 files in only one, i just dont know how.
All help is much apreciated :)

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php  use  `/inserir.php?myExampleVariable=Senha`

Comment: i dont know if i understand sry, how do i use that? (im noob XD)

Comment: You can use the single form element for all the input elements. But please make sure you provide unique names and ids to all the input elements (eg, <button id="btn1"..., <btn id="btn2" ...

Then in insert.php you check the id of the element and do the insert logic as required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add submit buttons with same name but different values.Retrieve the value by `$_POST['name']`

**HTML**

```
<form  action="inserir.php" method="post">
   <button name="val" type="submit" value="A">Senha A</button>
<button name="val" type="submit" value="B">Senha B</button>
<button name="val" type="submit" value="C">Senha C</button>
<button name="val" type="submit" value="D">Senha D</button>
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
include 'bdados.php';

$val = $_POST['val'];

$query = "INSERT into `tipo1`(`senhaa`) VALUES (  '$val' )";


mysqli_query($dbconn, $query);

header("location: index.php");



 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling your database schema could be improved, but without knowing the scope of your software, it's hard to make a recommendation. It looks like you want to change the table & the column-name based upon the value that is submitted. There are several different approaches that could help.

I'll change your query code to use a prepared statement (with [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php), as that's what I know)

## PHP Switch

You'll have one file that handles all four of those submissions.

```php
include 'bdados.php';

$key = array_keys($_POST)[0];
$value = $_POST[$key];
switch ($key){
    case 'A':
        $column = 'senhaa';
        $table = 'tipo1';
        break;
    case 'B':
        $column = 'senhab';
        $table = 'tipo2';
        break;
    case ...
}


//The table name is hard-coded, so that part is not vulnerable to SQL injection
$query = "INSERT into `{$tableName}`(`senhaa`) VALUES ( :newValue )";
$bind = [':newValue'=>$value];

$pdo = new PDO(...);
$statement = $pdo->prepare($query);
$statement->execute($bind);//pass the ':newValue' to be bound
//Without binding, somebody could submit: `'');DELETE FROM senhaa WHERE (TRUE`
// This would close your INSERT statement with an empty value & delete everything from your table


// print_r($statement->errorInfo()); //for debugging if it doesn't work

header("location: index.php");
```

### PHP Array

This will be much like above, but we'll replace the `switch` step with an array like:

```php
$info = [
    "A"=>['table'=>'tipo1','column'=>'tipo2']
    "B"=> ['table'=>'tipo2'...]
    ...
];
$table = $info[$key]['table'];
$column = $info[$key]['column'];
```

## Hidden HTML Inputs

Another approach could be to send identifying information through hidden input fields. While you should NOT send a table name this way, you could send some kind of identifier & then use the array-method above to map identifier to table info.

```html
<form  action="inserir-todo.php" method="post">
   <button name="D" type="submit" value="D">Senha D</button>
   <input type="hidden" name="identifier" value="the-fourth-table" />
</form>
```

Then you'd do:

```php
$key = $_POST['identifier'];
$table = $info[$key]['table'];
...
```

Comment: i basicaly have 3 columns, id, senhaa  and data (witch is date in portuguese) and i just want to add "A" to the senhaa column, it's basically it